# How to view two tables data on the same blade template (view)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a DB with multiple tables. I want to display the DB data on my laravel application. I want to display two tables data on the same page. I have created the model, view, and controller for the app but I am being able to display only one table. I cannot show the other table.
I think I need to define a model with multiple relationships which I am not getting how to do.

My tables are called **posts** and **videos** I have nothing on my model. the controller and the view is given below.

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('landing')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@extends('layouts.navbar')

@section('title')
    Landing Page
@endsection

@section('content')
<main class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">
                {{ $post->title }}
                {{ $post->brief }}
                {{ $post->body }}
                {{ $post->cover_image }}
            </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        @endforeach
      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        @foreach ($videos as $video)
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <a href="/videos/{{ $video->id }}">
                {{ $video->title }}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
@endsection
```

**Route on the web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/', 'VideosController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');


Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('videos', 'VideosController');


Auth::routes();
```

**Controller for videos data table**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VideosController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $videos = Video::all();
        return view('landing')->with('videos', $videos);
    }
}
```

**On this code I see this problem**
[image: On this code I get this problem]

If I remove the route for videos on my web.php I could see posts data.
So how could I display both the posts and the videos data at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass both Model together :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Video;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VideosController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $videos = Video::all();
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('landing', compact('videos','posts'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function profile($id)
{
    $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
    $measurements =  DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE custom_id = '$id'") );
    $customers = DB::table('customers')->where('customer_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return view('measurements.profile', compact('measurements','customers'));
}
```